# Contact Form using jQuery, AJAX, PHP does not send field values in email

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I've been looking at all the similar questions but still could'nt find my issue.

I receive blank email from the contact form...

Here is the html contact form:

```
<form id="main-contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post" action="sendmail.php">
<div class="form-group">
<input id="name" type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Nom" required>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" name="subject" class="form-control" placeholder="Sujet" required>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<textarea name="message" class="form-control" rows="8" placeholder="Message" required  </textarea>
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Envoyer</button>
</form>
```

Here is the PHP file:

```
<?php
$name       = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['name'])); 
$from       = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['email'])); 
$subject    = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['subject'])); 
$message    = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['message'])); 
$to         = 'info@pca.ch';

$headers   = array();
$headers[] = "MIME-Version: 1.0";
$headers[] .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf8";
$headers[] .= "From: {$name} <{$from}>";
$headers[] .= "Reply-To: <{$from}>";
$headers[] .= "Subject: {$subject}";
$headers[] .= "X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

?>
```

And here is the jquery code:

```
// Contact form
var form = $('#main-contact-form');
form.submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var form_status = $('<div class="form_status"></div>');
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        beforeSend: function(){
            form.prepend( form_status.html('<p><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Envoi...</p>').fadeIn() );
        }
    }).done(function(data){
        form_status.html('<p class="text-success">Votre message a bien été envoyé. Nous vous contacterons dès que possible.</p>').delay(3000).fadeOut();
    });
});
```

Website is [www.pca.ch](http://www.pca.ch) (french)

If I serialize it works but I got stuck in [www.pca.ch/sendmail.php](http://www.pca.ch/sendmail.php) and don't get the confirmation message.

Thank you very much for your help !
Orazio

The best I could achieve is that:

add serialize:
url: $(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(),

but then I need to remove $headers in php otherwise I get errors.

And the problem is that I don't get confirmation in line:
}).done(function(data){
form_status.html('Votre message a bien été envoyé. Nous vous contacterons dès que possible.

').delay(3000).fadeOut();
});

And mostly, got stock in [www.pca.ch/sendmail.php](http://www.pca.ch/sendmail.php) blank page !!

Comment: Add [error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/) to the
top of your file(s) _while testing_ right after your opening PHP tag for example. 
Even if you are developing on a server configured as LIVE you will now see any errors. 
`<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: It looks like you forgot to send any data on your AJAX call in the js

Comment: TYPO! You are missing a `>` in `<textarea name="message" class="form-control" rows="8" placeholder="Message" required  </textarea>`

Comment: I think you pass data with ajax request.I'm not sure but you can get data with out pass through ajax. Here is the link to pass data by data variable.
https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: RiggsFolly thanks for your help: TYPO: error pasting... I do have <textarea name="message" class="form-control" rows="8" placeholder="Message" required></textarea>

Comment: Ok, but you still dont appear to be sending any data from the Ajax call to the PHP

Comment: RiggsFolly could you please explain how I forgot to send any data on AJAX call ??

Comment: `method: "POST", url: $(this).attr('action'), data {name: $('#name').val , email: $('#email').val, subject: $('#subject).val, message: $('#message').val},`

Comment: it's like the serialize, it works but then I get this:
Warning: mail(): Found numeric header (0) in /home/clients/730072df783cf8df10d603d0130e9cc0/web/sendmail.php on line 19

Warning: mail(): Found numeric header (1) in /home/clients/730072df783cf8df10d603d0130e9cc0/web/sendmail.php on line 19

Warning: mail(): Found numeric header (2) in /home/clients/730072df783cf8df10d603d0130e9cc0/web/sendmail.php on line 19

Warning: mail(): Found numeric header (3) in /home/clients/730072df783cf8df10d603d0130e9cc0/web/sendmail.php on line 19

Answer (score 1):

I think you have an error in

```
$headers   = array();
$headers[] = "MIME-Version: 1.0";
$headers[] .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf8";
$headers[] .= "From: {$name} <{$from}>";
$headers[] .= "Reply-To: <{$from}>";
$headers[] .= "Subject: {$subject}";
$headers[] .= "X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion();
```

it should be like

```
$headers = array(
    'From' => 'webmaster@example.com',
    'Reply-To' => 'webmaster@example.com',
    'X-Mailer' => 'PHP/' . phpversion()
);
```